# Converting string to Date time - performance issues

Tags: pandas, performance, datetime, strptime

I'm currently working with large files, each file contain 65 million rows (size about 2.5 GB) and I need to convert one of the columns into DateTime (the date format is `2019-12-03 08:04:00.200`)

I have tried 3 ways to do so.

1. reading the file as data-frame and then using pd.to_datetime()
2. reading the file as data-frame - then using `.apply(lambda x : datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')`
3. converting the column using date parser while reading the file as data-frame

The 3rd option is the fastest (then the second and finally the first).
but they all take more than 25 minutes per file.

Is there a faster option ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use stick with `pd.to_datetime`.

> I tried all of the usual ways to make things fast like using `numpy` or `numba` but it isn't faster.

## Speed tests

Firts let's create the data to test it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

size = 100_000

data = {
    "year": np.random.choice([str(x) for x in range(2000, 2020)], size),
    "month": np.random.choice([str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(1, 12)], size),
    "day": np.random.choice([str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(1, 28)], size),
    "hour": np.random.choice([str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(24)], size),
    "minute": np.random.choice([str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(60)], size),
    "second": np.random.choice([str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(60)], size),
    "cent": np.random.choice([str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(100)], size),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data.values(), index=data.keys()).T
```

And then the `date` column:

```py
df["date"] = (
    df["year"] + "-" +
    df["month"] + "-" +
    df["day"] + " " +
    df["hour"] + ":" +
    df["minute"] + ":" +
    df["second"] + "." +
    df["cent"]
)
```

And for the numba test:

```py
from numba import jit

@jit
def cast_numba(x):
    return x.astype(np.datetime64)
```

Now we can test all of them:

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
1.07 s ± 71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df["date"].values.astype(np.datetime64)
2.04 s ± 73.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit cast_numba(df["date"].values)
2.24 s ± 394 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df["date"].apply(lambda x : datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
23 s ± 1.38 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```